# Code from Recorded Macro doesn't appear in Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Whenever I try to record a macro in Excel for Mac in order to view the code and try to customize it, there is no code to see. All I see is:

```
Sub MacroN()
'
'
'
End Macro()
```

Why can't I view the code so I can start to make adjustments to my macros?

Comment: There are few commands which cannot be captured by a macro recorder. It is applicable for Win-Excel as well. What exactly are you trying to record?

Comment: I just want to record anything and see the code so I can start learning VBA. I was recording changing a cell to text with 11 digits and applying it to a long column of numbers. No matter what I tried recording nothing appeared in the macro script.